# .replace(list(x), "") Doesn't Work Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I wrote code:

```
List<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> Prices = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<String> Dates =  new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> Hours =  new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> iDs =  new ArrayList<String>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView resultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMyReceipts);
    SearchView m = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.action_search);

    HashMap<String, String> NamePrice = new HashMap<>();

    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

    Names.add("Starbucks"); Prices.add(11.99); Dates.add("01/01/2017"); Hours.add("9:33");
    Names.add("Apple Store"); Prices.add(500.00); Dates.add("01/01/2017"); Hours.add("9:30");
    Names.add("Esselunga"); Prices.add(135.67); Dates.add("01/01/2017"); Hours.add("11:51");
    Names.add("Mediaworld"); Prices.add(19.98); Dates.add("01/01/2017"); Hours.add("12:03");
    Names.add("Starbucks"); Prices.add(11.99); Dates.add("01/01/2017"); Hours.add("12:47");

    for (int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++) {
        iDs.add(";+@:" + i + ":@+;");
        NamePrice.put(iDs.get(i) + Names.get(i), "    " + Prices.get(i).toString() + "€" + "  -  " + Dates.get(i) + "  " + Hours.get(i));
    }



    List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {"First", "Second"},
            new int[] {R.id.listitemTitle, R.id.listitemSubItem});

    //Integer x = 0;
    //int x = -1;
    Iterator it = NamePrice.entrySet().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < iDs.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        resultMap.put("First", pair.getKey().toString().replace(iDs.get(i), ""));
        resultMap.put("Second", pair.getValue().toString());
        listItems.add(resultMap);
    }
    //test.setText(IDs.get(x - 1));

    resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

This should replace all the IDs into "". It doesn't. So the output could be: ;+@:0:@+;NAME1    12.99                         ;+@:1:@+;NAME2 0.99
But in the second loop, if I say

```
resultMap.put("First", pair.getKey().toString().replace(IDs.get(0), ""));
```

it replaces correctly the element 0.
The output would be: NAME1    12.99                         ;+@:1:@+;NAME2 0.99

Comment: because `replace` gives you new string object , old one is not modified

Comment: so, how can I do? @PavneetSingh

Comment: wait , you mean , inside loop ,using index , your replace is not working , seems like i interpret your question in other way

Comment: yeah, I mean that in the loop, using the i index, my replace isn't working. But if I use, for example, 0 as index, it corectly replaces element 0 @PavneetSingh

Comment: simply use debugging , print the value of `pair.getKey().toString()` and `IDs.get(i)` and see it yourself , what exactly are the values

Comment: I did it, the values are the same @PavneetSingh

Comment: In Java use lowerCamelCase for variables.`IDs`, `Names`, `Prices` etc look like classes

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did it, is it more clear? @weston

Comment: Agree, @weston, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Comment: what is a MCVE? @OleV.V.

Comment: Sorry, MCVE is short for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Just follow the link in the previous comment.

Comment: Edited @OleV.V.

Comment: Could it be that you are not getting the entries of `NamePrice` in the order you expect, and therefore try to replace a different ID from the one you have? Which obviously wouldn’t replace anything. `NamePrice` is a `HashMap`. A `HashMap`’s iterator does not return the entries in any specific order, particularly not in the order they were inserted. You may try a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: God, you're right. How can I replace then? Should I do it after the iteration or is it too late?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It works perfectly @OleV.V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the entries of `NamePrice` in the order you expect. I inserted a `System.out.println()` in your second `for` loop and got the output in this order:

```
;+@:3:@+;Mediaworld
;+@:0:@+;Starbucks
;+@:4:@+;Starbucks
;+@:1:@+;Apple Store
;+@:2:@+;Esselunga
```

So you are trying to replace `;+@:0:@+;` in `;+@:3:@+;Mediaworld` and so forth. That doesn’t replace anything. The reason is that `NamePrice` is a `HashMap`. A `HashMap`’s iterator does not return the entries in any specific order, particularly not in the order they were inserted.

You may use a `LinkedHashMap` instead:

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> NamePrice = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Its iterator returns the entries in the order they were created. So now the replacements work.

Comment: Only one word: Awesome